# Partial installation of Nvidia drivers to obtain libcuda.so file

Tags: cuda, installation, driver, nvidia

I was trying to build the Rodinia benchmark suite in my Ubuntu 12.04 server

On running the make command I was getting the error

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcuda
```

I knew that the libcuda.so file is obtained on proper installation of Nvidia drivers. But dont have the GPU on the server so that I can install it. I need the Rodinia suite to test a GPU simulator.

Is there any way to obtain the libcuda.so file something like partially installing the Nvidia driver.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you know how to [download an NVIDIA driver](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).
You can select a recent driver, like [319.72](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/319.72/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.72.run), and it will work with pretty much any CUDA version you may want to use.  Newer drivers are backward compatible with older CUDA versions.  So if you pick 3192.72, for example, it should work just fine with CUDA 5.5, 5.0, 4.2, 4.1, 4.0, etc.

I'm speaking about standard usage with GPUs, not with emulators.  Your mileage may vary there.

If you run an nvidia driver installer package like so:

```
sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.72.run --help
```

You will get some command-line help (and the installer won't do anything).

If you inspect that command line help, you will see that you can get more advanced options by specifying:

```
sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.72.run --advanced-options
```

From the options we find there, we can run:

```
sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.72.run -x --keep --target mydirectory
```

Where `mydirectory` is the directory name where you want the extracted files to go.  Don't create `mydirectory` ahead of time, the installer will create it for you.  None of the above steps require root user privilege.

After you run the above command, you will find a `libcuda.so.319.72` file in that directory.  This is the file you want, put it where you want it. The driver installer also creates a symlink to this file, you will probably want to do this manually:

```
ln -s -T libcuda.so.319.72 libcuda.so
```

So copy the libcuda.so.319.72 file to whichever directory you want it to be in, then do the symlink there.  On a typical RHEL 6.x install, this file would be in the `/usr/lib64` directory, but it may be different on your distro.  Copying the file to a system directory like `/usr/lib64` will probably require root user privilege.

If you have questions about how this works with your emulator, I don't know anything about that and wouldn't be able to offer any advice there.

Comment: I was getting the following in my Ubuntu server             /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcuda
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
where should I copy the libcuda file

Comment: I don't know, but if you included more complete information such as the makefile and the complete compile command that is generating the above error, as well as the complete error output, someone might be able to tell you.  The compile/link command that is failing probably has some link library switches like `-L/path/to/libraries` and if you put the libcuda.so file in that path, it would probably find it.

Comment: Actually I don't have /usr/lib64 directory in my server. It has only the /usr/lib and /usr/lib32 directories. Does it make any difference......